# Why doesn't .NET Core and xUnit recognise my imported namespaces?

Tags: .net-core, xunit.net

I have a project that compiles that I want to test using xUnit. However although the project lets me add the references and builds, as soon as I add a `using` statement to the test class I get the red squiggly lines and the error "type or namespace could not be found."

Even though the xproj of the project I want to test has been added to references, and the namespaces do exist. It has to be something I have done, but I can't see what. Using earlier versions of .net, I have added references to test projects hundreds of times without an issue.

So what is different in the way .NET works, and why does it not recognize my namespaces in my referenced assemblies?

**Update**: I have removed xUnit and got MSTest working, but I have the same issue. So this may be a feature of the way I have dotnetcore set up, and the references in my json files more than anything else.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your `project.json` and relevant code. My guess is that you aren't referencing your main project from your test project correctly. Are you using `target: project` in project.json? (See the example in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

This structure works for me in .NET Core 1.0:

**global.json**

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
}
```

**src/MyLibrary/project.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": { },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      }
    }
  },
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

**test/MyLibrary.Test/project.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "2.2.0-preview2-build1029",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "MyLibrary": {
      "target": "project",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "xunit": "2.1.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "testRunner": "xunit",
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Using this directory and project structure, both the Visual Studio Test Explorer and `dotnet test` work and can run xUnit tests.

Comment: I cut and pasted your suggestion of json files directly into my project but I get the same issue. As son as I add in references to my types in the test project, I get the red squiggles under the namespaces and I can't reference anything useful in my project.

A colleague has suggested that they read that xUnit and MSTest don't work with imported assemblies from web projects yet. 

Thats something I'll need to research, but if true, then its a major faux pas for the release team IMO

Comment: @Matt What happens when you run `dotnet restore`? What happens when you compile?

Comment: Restore completes fine. Just some comments about lock files not changing, tghough it does also restore Iisintegration.Tools.
Compile - If import namespaces via using I get CS2046 - Type or namespace errors. If I comment them out its all fine. Basic asserts run fine no matter what (Assert.Equal(2,2);